# REST-API V2 returns server error without details

Tags: rest, error-handling, cuba-platform

If I post a app$customer to my sample cuba app, I get an error. The error caused by malformed json. I get an exception during db transaction...

The server sends a 500 error and this json:

```
{
  "error": "Server error",
  "details": ""
}
```

What should I configure to get a detailed message? Now I have to go through the catalina.out. It will be nice to see the error in the server response.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such configuration. In one of future releases we'll handle malformed JSON for entities REST controller and probably we'll add some configuration parameter that will return exception stacktrace to the client in case of unknown server errors.